# HTML to PDF with node-wkhtmltopdf crashing on a Digital Ocean Droplet server

Tags: node.js, ubuntu, npm, digital-ocean, wkhtmltopdf

I'm trying to generate a pdf file from html and would like to know the best way. I've tried html-pdf, pdf-puppeteer, node-wkhtmltopdf.

The first 2 crash the server when used giving 0 errors on a Digital Ocean Droplet using an Ubuntu image. They work fine on my computer (MAC OS), but fail to where on the server. When I tried node-wkhtmltopdf, which looked promising:

```
var wkhtmltopdf = require('wkhtmltopdf');

wkhtmltopdf(html).pipe(res);
```

It crashed giving an error message:
>

> Error: qt.qpa.screen: QXcbConnection: Could not connect to display
>
> Could not connect to any X display

I would like to know the best way I can create pdfs using a Digital Ocean Droplet.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found the solution, the qt is broken for the version which is installed using 'apt-get install' on ubuntu.

So, I installed wkhtmltopdf from the git repository and it worked fine.

https://github.com/wkhtmltopdf/wkhtmltopdf/releases/